# Should Quality of Life-scales (QoL) be included when measuring subjective well-being (SWB)?

Tags: well-being

I am trying to figure out how subjective well-being is operationalized in relation to a systematic review.

Some authors seems to include CES-D scales when reviewing well-being, categorizing it as "negative affect". Others include quality of life scales, which measures other non-subjective factors.

What scales best operationalize SWB and should QoL-scales be included?